# Oracle DbContext .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, dbcontext

Hi this is my first post here. I am using DbContext to get data from Oracle database. Could you tell me please, what i am doing wrong. I get no errors but get no data.

```
public class OracleContext : DbContext
{
    public OracleContext()
        : base("OracleConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("ROLES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(role => role.ROLE_ID).HasColumnName("ROLE_ID").HasColumnType("");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(role => role.USER_ROLE).HasColumnName("USER_ROLE").HasColumnType("VARCHAR");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public int ROLE_ID { get; set; }
    public string USER_ROLE { get; set; }
}
```

And controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        OracleContext ctx = new OracleContext();

        ViewBag.c = ctx.Roles.Count();
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: have you added data to the Roles table ?

Comment: Is there actually any data in the DB?

Comment: Yes, there is data in DB and i have tried adding data with
    ctx.Roles.Add() 
No error, but it did not add anything.